# How to Create Multiple Frequency Tables with Percentages Across Factor Variables using Purrr::map

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmosaic) for "happy" dataset.
```

I feel like this should be a somewhat simple thing to achieve, but I'm having difficulty with percentages when using purrr::map together with table(). Using the "happy" dataset, I want to create a list of frequency tables for each factor variable. I would also like to have rounded percentages instead of counts, or both if possible.

I can create frequency precentages for each factor variable separately with the code below.

```
with(happy,round(prop.table(table(marital)),2))
```

However I can't seem to get the percentages to work correctly when using table() with purrr::map. The code below doesn't work...

```
happy%>%select_if(is.factor)%>%map(round(prop.table(table)),2)
```

The second method I tried was using tidyr::gather, and calculating the percentage with dplyr::mutate and then splitting the data and spreading with tidyr::spread.

```
TABLE<-happy%>%select_if(is.factor)%>%gather()%>%group_by(key,value)%>%summarise(count=n())%>%mutate(perc=count/sum(count))
```

However, since there are different factor variables, I would have to split the data by "key" before spreading using purrr::map and tidyr::spread, which came close to producing some useful output except for the repeating "key" values in the rows and the NA's.

```
TABLE%>%split(TABLE$key)%>%map(~spread(.x,value,perc))
```

So any help on how to make both of the above methods work would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Something like `happy %>% select_if(is.factor) %>% map(~round(prop.table(table(.x)), 2))`?  See what you can pass to the `.f` argument in `map` and some of the Examples on the help page for other options.

Comment: For your second option, removing `count` from the dataset prior to `split`/`map` will solve most of the problems.  You may also want to remove the `NA` groups in your `value` column.

Comment: Those options seem to work. I can give you credit if you add official answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function or a formula to get your first option to work.  Here's the formula option.

```
happy %>% 
    select_if(is.factor) %>% 
    map(~round(prop.table(table(.x)), 2))
```

In your second option, removing the `NA` values and then removing the `count` variable prior to spreading helps.  The order in the result has changed, however.

```
TABLE = happy %>%  
    select_if(is.factor) %>% 
    gather() %>% 
    filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
    group_by(key, value) %>% 
    summarise(count = n()) %>% 
    mutate(perc = round(count/sum(count), 2), count = NULL)

TABLE %>% 
    split(.$key) %>% 
    map(~spread(.x, value, perc))
```